# Transformer is generating less voltage than expected

Tags: troubleshooting

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVh93t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was tried to make a super simple inverter (consisting of a transformer, a single MOSFET, and a capacitor,) which is capable of providing 2 times the voltage or at most 1 or 2 volt less on its output.

The result was much worse than I expected.

I got like 59 millivolts AC RMS output with a 4.28 volt DC supply

I tried increasing the input voltage,  which result in noise and heating for the MOSFET. That was quiet worrying so I decreased the voltage again.

**I&Os**

Inputs

- U = 4.28v DC
- I = 0.054a

Output

- U = 59.2 mV AC RMS
- f = 6.951 kHz

**specs**

- FQP8N60C transistor [ [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/648283/FAIRCHILD/FQP8N60C.html) ]
- CBB22 155J400V capacitor 400V 1.4 uF
- Ferrite transformer from flyback [(10, 10): primary , (20): secondary ]
- 330 ohm 1/4 watt

Is there any thing I should improve?

**Edited #1**

I got some improvement after I increased the resistance of the resistor to 2k in the gate since it can regulate much of the current that heats up the FET so I was able to cranck up to 11v.

However I got like 200mv AC rms in 9.01 v input which was bad

Comment: _"Ferrite transformer from flyback"_ - exactly what is this? Please post a photo of the entire circuit, including power supply.  _"I got like 59 millivolts AC RMS... Output U = 59.2V AC RMS"_- one of these is wrong, please correct it. What did you use to measure the AC voltage and frequency?

Comment: "*capable of providing 2 times the voltage*" -- since you are feeding it DC, you must expect DC at the output, but I don't see anywhere any rectification, and you seem to be measuring AC. Frankly, I'm surprised your transistor hasn't blown up with the way you're driving it, either by overvoltage, or by heating through linear driving (as opposed to switching).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen you are right I may expect dc but even if i rectlify it i may get less volt dc wont magically increase it if the ac is less

Comment: @BruceAbbott https://photos.app.goo.gl/X2E3y9MF6fjk7HaHA

Answer (score 1):

> I tried increasing the input voltage, which result in noise and
> heating for the MOSFET. That was quiet worrying so I decreased the
> voltage again.

The [FQP8N60C](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FQP8N60C-195031.pdf) has a Gate threshold voltage of 2 to 4 V. At 4.28 V it is barely turning on, which is why you only have a low level oscillation. You need to increase the voltage to get the FET to turn on harder. However this will also increase current draw. With few turns on the primary the inductance is low so you need a high operating frequency to keep the current down.

The large value capacitor across the winding is not helping. If you want a low frequency then you need a lot more turns. If you don't care about frequency then use a smaller value capacitor to allow it to oscillate faster (but be aware that your multimeter probably won't be accurate at higher frequency).

Normally a circuit like this is used in [flyback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter) converters that oscillate by driving the core into saturation, and use a diode to rectify the high output voltage pulse produced when the transistor switches off. If you want sine wave AC output then the transistor will have to operate in [class A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes#Class_A) ('linear' or 'single-ended') which is very inefficient and will make it run hot.

Most [inverters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter#Circuit_description) use a push-pull configuration with 2 transistors (one on each side of the primary winding), producing a square wave output which is more efficient because the transistors act as switches rather than linear amplifiers. If you have another FET then wire it symmetrically like [this](http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Basic_Circuit/12_V_INPUT_SIMPLE_INVERTER.html):-

[image]

Comment: I really like your answer but in "With few turns on the primary the inductance is low so you need a high operating frequency to keep the current down." this phrase I got somewhat confused AFAIK the lesser the turn the higher frequency is and higher current draw will be since L = Φ(magnetic flux)/ current

Comment: The natural oscillating frequency is is higher with lower inductance, but the amplitude will build up until either the core (blocking mode) or the FET (linear mode) saturates. You don't want the FET to saturate because you want full voltage across the core and low loss in FET. In linear mode the circuit draws almost constant power, with the FET consuming ~50% at maximum output, increasing to ~100% as output loading reduces....

Comment: The core saturates at a particular flux level, which requires more current when inductance is lower (fewer turns). So to reduce current you either need more turns (= higher inductance) or you must drive the FET from a separate oscillator at a higher frequency that avoids core saturation. Alternatively you could use a smaller core that needs less flux to reach saturation.